# regex / javascript : Filter & replace groups with same values from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
var array=[
           '100000011022', 
           '122339311022', 
           '988881233221',
           '000130009999',
          ]
```

... and I'd like to **find groups with the same column** (LENGTH : minimum 2, maximum 10) and replace every group element with another value (e.g. 0).

> e.g ---> `988881233221` => `900001200001` *(found '8888', '33', '22')*

SO the result should look like this:

```
var result=[
           '100000000000', 
           '100009300000', 
           '900001200001',
           '000130000000',
           ]
```

Because I have no clue how to use regex this is all that I got so far, I'm sorry!

```js
var array=[
 '100000011022', 
 '122339311022', 
 '988881233221',
 '000130009999'
]

var result = array.join('\n').replace(/.{4,10}[^.]/g, function(a) {
  return a.replace(/./g,'0')
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/SZ1Vlh/1)

```
(\d)\1
```

Replacement: `00`

#### Usage

```js
const regex = /(\d)\1/g;
var array=[
  '100000011022', 
  '122339311022', 
  '988881233221',
  '000130009999'
]
const subst = `00`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
array.forEach(function(s, i) {
  array[i] = s.replace(regex, subst);
});

console.log(array);
```

---

### Explanation

- `(\d)` Capture a single digit into capture group 1
- `\1` Match the same text as most recently matched by capture group 1

Answer (score 0):

Use \1 to reference any matched symbol.

```js
var array=[
 '100000011022', 
 '122339311022', 
 '988881233221',
 '000130009999'
]

var result = array.join('\n').replace(/(.)\1{1,9}/g, function(a) {
   return a.replace(/./g,'0')
})
console.log(result)
```